# Transliterate Characters in Hex in Bash

Tags: bash, perl, sed, tr

i have a set of hexadecimals that i d like to transliterate to another set of hexadecimals, in example :

```
x00 -> x20
xB0 -> x20
x21 -> x40
x80-xFF -> x20
x22 -> x43
```

I know i can chain sed statements like :

```
sed -i.bak $'s/[\x80-\xFF]/\x20/g'
```

or like :

```
sed -e 's/\x00/\x20/g;s/\xB0/\x20/g'
```

but is there a way to "break" those separate changes by line so its more readable? Like :

```
sed -e '
 s/\x00/\x20/g;
 s/\xB0/\x20/g;
 .
 .
 .
 ' File_In > File_out
```

If its not possible, could this be done with perl? Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you have written, other than that the semicolons aren't needed as you are separating your sed commands with line breaks.

Comment: `xB0 -> x20` is redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass multiple expressions (`-e`) to `sed`:

```
sed \
    -e 's/\x00/\x20/g' \
    -e 's/\xB0/\x20/g' \
    -e 's/\x21/\x40/g' \
    -e 's/[\x80-\xFF]/\x20/g' \
    -e 's/\x22/\x43/g' File_In > File_out
```

Comment: Thank you, can i ask you if this will re-read the file from the beginning for every application of sed / change i require, i m asking because the files are upwards of 300 mb each. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't know definitely, but my gut tells me that it does not re-read the file for each `-e` as that would be very inefficient.

Comment: Just looked at the source code to `sed` and it compiles all of the expressions (`-e`) into a single "program" that it then runs. So no, it does not re-read the file each time.

Comment: Be careful. This approach breaks if you have mappings such as A->B plus B->C

Answer (score 2):

The following still defines the mapping as a map, but generates a single, efficient `tr///` to do the actual work.

```
perl -i~ -p <(
   perl -e'
      my %tr = (
         ( map { chr($_) => " " } 0x00, 0x80..0xFF ),
         q{!} => q{@},
         q{"} => q{C},
      );

      my $s = join "", map { sprintf "\\x%02X", ord($_) } keys   %tr;
      my $r = join "", map { sprintf "\\x%02X", ord($_) } values %tr;
      print("tr/$s/$r/");
  '
) myfile
```

---

Faster?

```
sed -i~ <(
   perl -e'
      my %tr = (
         ( map { chr($_) => " " } 0x00, 0x80..0xFF ),
         q{!} => q{@},
         q{"} => q{C},
      );

      my $s = join "", map { sprintf "\\x%02X", ord($_) } keys   %tr;
      my $r = join "", map { sprintf "\\x%02X", ord($_) } values %tr;
      print("y/$s/$r/");
  '
) myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `y` command to [transliterate](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-49):

```
$ sed 'y/\x20\x2B/\x21\x2D/' <<< "foo bar+more"
foo!bar-more
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl that would look like

```
perl -i.bak -pe '
    tr/\x00\x80-\xFF\xB0/\x20/;
    tr/\x21/\x40/;
    tr/\x22/\x43/;
' myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and Bash):

```
cat <<\! | sed -f - fileIn > fileOut
s/\x00/\x20/g
s/\xB0/\x20/g
.
.
.
!
```

Use a here-document and pass it as a script to sed using the `-f -` option.